# Redirect Using .htaccess file - Page/pagenumber

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am stuck with my limited knowledge of .htaccess file.

i am migrating from one site to another. lets say my old site is cws and my new site is sa

my old site cws urls are with cws/category/category name.. while my new website sa is without category.

I also change the slug of the categories.

i write a rule like

```
RewriteRule ^category/love/(.*) https://newdomain.com/angry-relationship-advise/$1 [R=301,L]
```

now on the google search i saw my categories pages are also index.

now if someone click on google like

http://oldsite/category/love/ its redirecting to https://newdomain.com/angry-relationship-advise

But if someone click on

http://oldsite/category/love/page/2 or http://oldsite/category/love/page/3 it didn't redirect to

https://newdomain.com/angry-relationship-advise/page/2 or https://newdomain.com/angry-relationship-advise/page/3

Can anyone help me with this. i have tried (.*) or $1 but its working for base url.. not with pages.

Looking for your help.

Comment: try in incognito mode

Comment: Hello Ben, I have tried. .but didn't work.. Can you tell me how the statement should look like.. the thing is it redirecting to the wrong url.. newdomain.com/love/page/2 does not exist.. i want it to redirect to https://newdomain.com/angry-relationship-advise/page/2